# how to properly bring out a modal "color"

Tags: theory, modes, modal

Let's please stay in the key of CMaj (C Ionian, D dorian, E phrygian, etc.)

If for example, if I have an underlying CMaj triad (C-E-G), but wanted to emphasize the middle note (E), I could solo using (E phrygian), or the CMaj scale, beginning on E.

Phrygian's formula is (1 - b2 - b3 - 4 - 5 - b6 - b7) or E-F-G-A-B-C-D

Phrygian's half-steps are between the (1 - b2) & the (5 - b6) or E - F & B - C

There has to be other ways to emphasize a particular mode & bring outs its flavor, other than just beginning on a certain root (ie; starting the CMaj scale on E, would yield E phrygian)

To really home in on the specific mode, would you target the modal root note (E) & only the notes that make up the half-step intervals (E - F) & (B - C)?

I've just recently read about "circling the root" of the mode? I guess this would mean to play the 7th & the 2nd often? Or alternate between 7-1, 1-2, 2-1, 1-7, etc.?

Comment: I can't imagine anything you could do with an E Phrygian scale over a C major chord that would make me think anything other than "C major, ending on the third."  The normal way to bring out a modal color is to use a modal harmonization, so centered on E minor.

Comment: Related: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/124546/in-modal-harmony-what-are-modal-tonic-chords/124547

Comment: @Tim what is the logic behind both answering the question and closing the question?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis  - having provided an answer, I considered it to be a dupe, later. However, it appears it's back in circulation. Didn't realise I could close single-handedly, though. (Which I think is what happened - my vtc has disappeared...) with no explanation forthcoming.

Comment: @Tim because of your gold tag badge for theory, your vote to close a question tagged [tag:theory] will be decisive.  Michael Curtis has the same gold tag badge, so his vote to reopen was also decisive.

Comment: @phoog - thanks for the enlightenment, I didn't know. In fact, I would rather have used my vtc, and waited to see if others felt it was a dupe too. So, if that's the case, I'm stuffed as far as that's concerned! Too much power for one person - beit me or MC, I feel... Next time I'll just comment that I think a question may be a dupe instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's please stay in the key of CMaj

To add "modal color" the idea is to add various modal degrees *relative* to the tonic of `C`.

So, with a key of `C` major, we can say the mode is either "major" or "ionian."

If you want to add a lydian flavor, raise the `F` to `F#`, because `C D E F# G A B C` would be `C` lydian.

Importantly, to get a lydian flavor you must both raise the `F` to `F#` (raise the fourth scale degree to an augmented fourth above the tonic) and also you must _maintain `C` as the tonic. Do not inadvertently have the key drift to `G` major or some other tonic.

Then just continue in the same way, but adding various other modal degrees. If you want a mixolydian flavor, lower the seventh scale degree `B` to `B♭`, and maintain a tonic of `C`.

> There has to be other ways to emphasize a particular mode & bring outs its flavor, other than just beginning on a certain root (ie; starting the CMaj scale on E, would yield E phrygian)

No. Starting a `C` major scale on `E` is not a way to get the phrygian mode.

[image]

Both of those are simply a `C` major chord, in `C` major. The second example, with the scale starting on `E`, does absolutely nothing to change the mode. To make it sound phrygian we need some modal pitches to get `E` to sound not like the third scale degree of `C` major, but as the tonic of `E` phrygian. `C` major and `E` phrygian are seemingly the same set of pitches, but in a Renaissance modal style, the new pitch that will differentiate from `C` major turns out to be the `G`...

[image]

> I've just recently read about "circling the root" of the mode? I guess this would mean to play the 7th & the 2nd often? Or alternate between 7-1, 1-2, 2-1, 1-7, etc.?

Yes, but that should be stated as "circling the tonic of the mode." Roots are the foundation of chords. Tonics are the foundation of modes. If we want to a show adding modal color from major to a mode, maintaining the same tonic, it might be easier to show with something like major to mixolydian, rather than the extreme of major to phrygian...

[image]

...that is sort of a folk or pop take on modal harmony.

If you did something similar from major to phrygian, it sounds pretty extreme...

[image]

There is an important mode mixture progression in classical harmony that should be mentioned, because you asked about phrygian mode, the Neapolitan `N6` chord...

[image]

...notice the `D` in the treble part is natural, and so the mode is minor, until it gets to the `D♭` in the `N6` chord.  Basically, the idea is when the subdominant (fourth scale degree, in this case `F`) is in the bass, instead of using `C` or `D` in the treble for either a `iv` or `iio6` chord, a `D♭` is used to get the modal color of phrygian, and create a strong chromatic enclosure around the tonic `C`.

If you want to play modally, without changing key signature, but shifting to the various "modal tonics" for a given key signature, I agree the `7-1-2` enclosure idea, the "circling the tonic" idea, will work. But, harmonically avoid playing a proper dominant/subdominant or any diminished chord. So, with a key signature of no sharps/flats, `C` major, the "modal tonics" you could target are `D, E, F, G, A`, play the triads for those tones, and the diatonic `II, IV, or VII` chords relative to them, excepting any of those chords that might be diminished...

```
Dm G  Dm    or    Dm C  Dm
Em Am Em    or    Em D  Em
F  G  F     or    F  Em F     (F C F too, just don't play B♭)
G  F  G     or    G  Dm G
Am G  Am    or    Am Em Am
```

...these choices are subjective, but you will find a lot of these progressions in modal folk music, depending on your rhythmic/melodic themes you could even get something that sounds like Satie or Debussy with those progressions.

Comment: "to get a lydian flavor you must both raise the F to F# (raise the fourth scale degree to an augmented fourth above the tonic) and also you must _maintain C as the tonic": alternatively, you continue to use the same set of pitch classes (e.g., the notes of the C major scale) but you change the pitch center, using in this example F as the tonic.

Comment: True. I tried to convey that in the rest of my answer.

Comment: Absolutely.  I probably wouldn't have added this nitpick were it not for the question's first sentence.

Comment: Sure, but if we are nitpicking you _cannot_ stay in the key `C` major and also be in `F` lydian, which IMO is the crux of the problem. If it had been stated as "let's maintain the key _signature_ of zero sharps/flats, C major, D dorian, etc..." it might have been clearer what needed explaining.

Comment: The OP wrote "bring out modal color" which I think would normally be understood as maintaining a tonic, altering modal degrees, but then the OP described changing tonics with incidental mode changes simply because the key signature was unchanged. I've not seen music, none I remember, that modulates like D dorian, E phrygian, F lydian, etc. I think it's a misunderstanding. I don't think they meant pandiatonicism. Modally-ambivalent-diatonicism maybe? It's hard to untangle concisely.

Answer (score 0):

By playing a C major chord, it won't really matter which note you start on - and there are songs which start on every note of the C major scale with a C chord underneath - it will sound like we're in key C.

E Phrygian is essentially a minor 'key', so using Em underneath will help emphasise this. By visiting Em often - along with some E notes - you'll give more of a Phrygian feel. Of course you can use the other chords that are diatonic to E Phrygian (same as C major, but it's also important as to *where* those chords go. Beginnings and particularly endings of phrases are important, just like if you were in key C, ending phrases on chord C and/or chord tones, it would indicate we're in key C.